# После обновления WebStorm пропал индикатор цвета

Tags: webstorm

После того как обновился до версии 2016 в редакторе css пропали индикаторы цвета (маленькие квадратики сбоку от кода). В настройках нашел только отображение цвета на его кодировке. Можно ли как-то вернуть прежний вид?

Answer (score 2):

В этих продуктах работает поиск по настройкам.
Можно было вбить слово `gutter` в поле поиска в окошке настроек, чтобы найти нужную.

Вот полный путь к нужной настройке:

File → Settings… → Editor → General → Appearance → **Show CSS color preview in gutter**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]